# Multiple overlapping animations on the same element in svg.js

Tags: animation, svg, svg.js

I want to start a animation on an element while a previous animation is still active. However, calling `animate()` on the element queues the new animation at the end of the current animation.

For example, consider an animation where an element is being moved to a new position. Now, I also want to make it fade out when it reaches a certain position. The following queues the “once” animation at the end of the move, rather than at 80%.

```
rect.animate(1000).move(100, 100)
    .once(0.8, function(pos, eased) {
                 rect.animate(200).opacity(0);
               });
```

How do I make the element start fading out when it reaches 80% of the move? The API seems to be designed for chaining animations rather simultaneous overlapping animations.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bit more complicated. Unforrtunately its not possible to "hack" into the current animation and add a new animation on the fly.
However what you can do is adding a new property which should be animated:

```
var fx = rect.animate(1000).move(100, 100)
    .once(0.8, function(pos, eased) {
             fx.opacity(0);
           });
```

As you will notice that has its own problems because the oopacity immediately jumps to 80%. So this is not an approach which works for you.

Next try: Use the `during` method:

```
  var morh = SVG.morph(

  var fx = rect.animate(1000).move(100, 100)
    .once(0.8, function(pos, eased) {
             fx.during(function(pos, morphFn, easedPos) {
                 pos = (pos - 0.8) / 0.2
                 this.target().opacity(pos)
             }
           });
```

We just calculate the opacity ourselves